# VBA Save to sub folder

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, save

I have a code that saves a PDF in the same folder as my workbook. I have a sub folder called PDF Files within the folder and I would like to save there. I can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.  Below is the code I have so far.

```
FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & .Range("F" & CustRow).Value & "_" & _
           .Range("K" & CustRow).Value & ".pdf"
```

Comment: Replace `"\"` with `"\PDF Files\"`?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I forgot to put the \ in the code to designate it as a folder, like \pdf files\.